# Spring RestTemplate: URI is not absolute

Tags: java, spring, uri

I'm trying to connect to a *Spring RESTful service* on the same server where my webapp is running.

I'd like to use a "relative" path because it could be installed on several environments (localhost, test, production) but I get the error message: `URI is not absolute`.

How can I call a service running on another webapp on the same server?

My code is like following:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
URI uri;
try {
    String url = "app2/myservice?par=1";
    uri = new URI(url);
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Thanks.

**Update:**

I solved it by getting the host, port, etc... from the `request`, could it be a right and elegant solution? This's my actual simplified code:

```
String scheme = request.getScheme();
String userInfo = request.getRemoteUser();
String host = request.getLocalAddr();
int port = request.getLocalPort();
String path = "/app2/myservice";
String query = "par=1";
URI uri = new URI(scheme, userInfo, host, port, path, query, null);
boolean isOK = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Boolean.class);
if (isOK) {
    System.out.println("Is OK");
}
```

Comment: Encoding is nog for urls! Its for parameter values. Remove this line: `String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(url, UTF_8);`

Comment: Ok, I removed the encode, but anyway I need to specify a relative url, is that possible? Thanks

Comment: Relative to what? Without any context, an application doesn't know how it was externally accessed. If you have access to the HttpServletRequest, you can see what that object thinks that your application was accessed at, but even that doesn't need to be perfect if there are reverse proxies in front of your own Java application server. Making a relative request is easy for javascript code running in a browser, but really hard for a serverside application.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Relative to current request, I've updated my question, what's about my current code? Thanks

Comment: probably you forgot Url's hostname (e.g. localhost:8080)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it as your code in the first snippet; the URI must FULLY identify the resource you are trying to get to. Your second snippet is the pretty much the only way you can do what you're trying to do. There may be other ways, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Of course, with your approach, you are dictating your system architecture and deployment model ***in code***, which is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Your URL `app2/myservice?par=1` is not complete if your service running on another web app or the same server.

You have to complete the path by giving base URL means `localhost:8080/yourApp/app2/myservice?par=1` then the things might work for you.

Also, check the Package access.

Answer (score 3):

Provide a full path like **http://localhost:8080/app2/myservice?par=1**.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using service discovery by using the Netflix Eureka discovery server. You need to provide a full path like http://app2/myservice?par=1.